# Default data type of the constants printed in System.out.print();

Tags: java

```
System.out.println(2147483647 + 1); //prints -2147483648
```

I know 2147483647 is the max value of integer data type. My question is why is this result calculated for Integer type, and why was it not considered for Long or double?

Because...

```
System.out.println(127+1);  //prints 128
```

here why is 127 not considered for Byte data type, resulting in the result to be -128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundmentally, you seem to not fully understand [literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). A number without a decimal point or suffix is always an `int`, regardless of it's magnitude. This can be further complicated by [implicit widening](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) when assigning to larger primitive datatypes (e.g. `int` may be implicitly widened to `long`).

So now we know that your two literals are `int`s. `int` + `int` is always `int`. It doesn't matter whether the result will overflow or not.

If you know or suspect that the constants will exceed the range of `int`, add the suffix `L` (i.e. `2147483647L` and `1L`) to explicitly declare that these are longs. `long` + `long` = `long`, so the result will not overflow in this case.

Answer (score 1):

println is overloaded with several inputs, your paramters are of type int so method will be called

```
public void print(int i) {

    write(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every number in java sorce code is by default an integer. If you like to have an other type like long, you need to extend your number with an 'L'  (e.g. 23409L) or you have to cast it. Only at initialization from a variable the compiler make the cast for you.

In many cases you can give byte or short also to methodes, even if they request for an integer parameter. But this only works because of java's conversions and promotions mechanism.

Because of all this functionalities some programmer mess up with the real data types they have at one point of the code.

For more infos visit the oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html